# How to lock screen orientation to landscape

Tags: android, android-orientation

I am using application which is of landscape mode which can capture user aadhar data by using RD Service but when i am connecting morpho device to the tab then 'Morpho SCL-RDService' application can register the morpho device which can make my current activity to portrait mode and then landscape mode.So is there any work around to fix the orientation which can not be changed due interference of any other application.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this in Manifest.xml file

```
 <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize‌​"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Solved my problem by adding android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"

Answer (score 4):

You need to set **`android:screenOrientation="landscape`"**  `Orientation` to your `Activity` in Manifest file

like this

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

         <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: i already added above line in the manifest but didn't worked for me !

Comment: @sanil **didn't worked for me**  can u  explain more

Comment: i am using RD service to register the morpho device.So when       
i am connecting device to the tab that Rd Service application can registering my device in the foreground which causes my current activity to portrait and then landscape(within 1 second) mode after registration of device.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);`

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the landscape layout of activity?

Comment: no i am not adding landscape layout anymore instead i used orientation mode in manifest file.

Comment: so addit. you are going to use it